# Changing Voluntary to Involuntary by will

Tags: cognitive-psychology, intelligence, brain-training, reaction-time

As we all know, certain actions like,

- blinking of eye
- breathing

all happen involuntarily, and we have the option to control them voluntarily as well(holding breath etc..) when needed.

But, once we change our focus on something else for a few minutes, we forget that we had voluntary control(like holding breath etc..), and involuntary actions takes place automatically.

So, Can we transfer ***voluntary control*** to ***involuntary*** by will?

P.S. Since the question is about experience, I couldn't ask more clearly. Sorry for that. :)

Comment: I imagine learning a skill, such as riding a bicycle or driving a car, would require initially voluntary control which becomes habit or involuntary.  Practice would be our will attempting to turn the voluntary control to the involuntary.